# Fastest Way to Dynamically shift a 16 bit register

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I want to design a module that shifts a 16 bits register n times where n is dynamically changing every time. I want to get the results in 1 clock cycle and I am using Xilinx Zynq FPGAs. I already know three implementations for my design but I want to know if other possible ways exists:

1- The first way that occurred to me is to use a sequential logic to do a single shift every cycle. In worst case, I need 16 cycles (if n=16) to do this shift.

2-The other way is to wire up 16 different combination of shifts and feed them into a multiplexer and use n to choose the shift I want. I can easily shift the input number by any number of times I get in a single cycle.

3- The third way is to use RAM based shift register in my FPGA

The first method obviously does not satisfy my constraint in which I want to get results in one clock cycles. The second methods seems to consume a lot of my fpga resources if I want to scale my design and the third method is using my valuable BRAMs. I was wondering if other ways exist?

Comment: 1) What gets shifted in? Just zeroes, or up to 16 bits of input every cycle? 2) How much of the output do you need access to? Just one bit or all 16 bits of the register?

Comment: 1) I shift in zeros
2) I need to access all 16 bits

Comment: 1) Then how does non-zero content get into the register? Is there some way to load it in parallel, or…?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the built-in shift operator?

assign x = y << z;

That will shift 'y' by 'z' positions adding zeros at the LS bits.
Of course 'x' must be big enough to hold the result. Which depends on the maximum value of 'z'.

It builds a so called *barrel shifter* and the synthesis tools are very good at making those efficient.

You will be hard pressed to find a more optimal solution.

Comment: I ended up designing a logarithmic shifter. Do you know if  '<<' in a xilinx tool can synthesize it into a logarithmic shifter?

Comment: Synthesis and logic optimisation have become very, very good. Don't forget that, unless you take specific steps, they are between your code and the real hardware. I would not be surprised if your code and the code above produce the same gates. Especially on an FPGA.